# rROC to calculate the best threshold, how to give it out?

Tags: r

I am using the package rROC in R to calculate and visualize the ROC curve.
After the curve is visualized, it is than possible to determin the best
binary classification result through determing the point which is 
more near to the left top corner (right positive rate). Now my question is,
how to give out the (best) threshold of this point which shows the
best classification result in the ROC curve?

Would be happy if someone would give me tips.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found it

--> it can be done with this command

coords(rocObject, "b", ret="t")

Comment: I was confused for a moment, I thought there was yet another ROC package out there named `rROC` (and that I couldn't get it to install). Turns out the package is actually named `pROC`. Thank you for figuring out this command, I've been using a more laborious manual calculation.